# How to get file extension from filename in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, substring

How to get file extension from filename in PostgreSQL 10

```
filename.zip
filename.tar.gz
filename.rar
filename.tar.bz2
```

It's like this down here

```
filename_202011120001.zip
filename_202011120002.tar.gz
filename_202011120003.rar
filename_202011120004.tar.bz2
```

Comment: And what do you want as a result?

Comment: For `filename.tar.gz`, do you want `.gz` or `.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring()`:

```
substring(filename from '\..*')
```

This captures everything from the first dot until the end of the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae4828aac6f9367d6fd4e85ef05b35ec)**:

```
select filename, substring(filename from '\..*') ext
from (values 
    ('filename.zip'), 
    ('filename.tar.gz'), 
    ('filename.rar'), 
    ('filename.tar.bz2')
) t(filename)
```

```
filename         | ext     
:--------------- | :-------
filename.zip     | .zip    
filename.tar.gz  | .tar.gz 
filename.rar     | .rar    
filename.tar.bz2 | .tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regexp_replace()` . . . but it is unclear what you want.  If you want to remove all characters up to and including the first period:

```
regexp_replace(filename, '^[^.]*[.]', '')
```

If you want to return the last suffix:

```
regexp_replace(filename, '^.*[.]([^.]+)$', '\1')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=94d40f87e67e0bf0bf33a564b18b197a) is a db<>fiddle.